# Bones Mirroring Opposite Rotation

Tags: animation, bones, constraints, mirror

All my bones are mirroring perfectly except for my fingers which for some reason rotate in the opposite direction. Not sure what might be causing this the only thing unique to these are that the tip copies some rotation from the middle finger bone, but I've switched this off and still they taunt me. Here's a video:
https://vimeo.com/513733570 Maybe someone knows what's happening? Thanks in advance :D.

I should also add that this seems only to happen in pose mode, in edit mode it works just fine.

Comment: Hello :). If you want to provide the blend, you can use https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer today apparently, the mirror is based on the roll of the bones so I needed to set one side to the negative roll value of the other then readjust all my constraints accordingly.